# Facebook Pixel not working for shopify buy button

Tags: shopify, facebook-pixel

I am creating custom sales page in Shopify and add to cart button using "Buy button" code. I have also used Facebook pixel but they are not working for this buy button. Please let me know how to make facebook pixel work with this buy button

Thanks

Comment: How are you adding FB pixel tag? With Google tag manager? Or just inserting a tag into markup?

Comment: I am adding manual code 
http://prntscr.com/h1ddyk

Replaced pixel id with XXXXXXXXXXXX

Comment: Can you please provide screenshot of your "Buy Button" code

Comment: http://prntscr.com/h1e16u
http://prntscr.com/h1e1me
http://prntscr.com/h1e1u9

Answer (score 0):

You can do this two way...
1st is just make a java script function and on the onsubmit event add the `fbq('track','AddToCart');` code inside it.

```
    function submitbuybutton(){ fbq('track','AddToCart');}
```

2nd you can make a form action and write down the facebook pixel fire complete code inside it with  `fbq('track','AddToCart');`